# How To Use Scanner Inside a Method

Tags: java.util.scanner

I am trying to use Scanner inside a method to read the value of a string that I am converting to an int. The method is inside a class, which is an object created by the class holding main.
Some psuedocode:

```
class Project1 {
    main() {
    Circle c = new Circle();
    c.createCircle();
    }
}
```

Now the class holding the scanner:
'''

```
public class Circle {
    public int radius = 0;

    public int createCircle() throws IOException {

    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the radius:");

    try {
        radius = Integer.parseInt(sc1.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a number.");
    } finally {
        sc1.close();
    }
    System.out.println("The radius is: " + radius);

    return radius;
}}
```

'''

Running this code returns the error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found.
It is thrown by the "radius = Integer.parseInt(sc1`enter code here`.nextLine());" line.

Thank you for any help!
Chuck

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, because I was also using scanner in my main method in the Project1 class, and closing that Scanner, I was closing Scanner across the whole application, and once closed, it seems it cannot be reopened, so I have commented out the code closing the scanner and will move that some place to where it will close with the whole application